# How I create this animation using CSS or Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I do have some HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="translate-bar"> 
  <div class="icon">
    <img src="images/translator-icon.png">
  </div>
  <div class="contents">        
    <p>tranlate contents</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using this Markup, I wanted to do an animation using CSS. Animation mean, I positioned "translate-bar" with `absolute` and `right:0`.

Then I need to display only "icon" image on the browser and then when a user click on or mouseover on icon `DIV` then I need to diplay "contents" `DIV`. Icon and contents DIVs display inline.

I tried it with CSS `transition`. but I couldn't figure this out.

My CSS:

```
.translate-bar {
    position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: table;
}

.icon {
    height: 50px;
}

img {
    width: 50px;
}

.contents {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #ebebeb;
}
```

Comment: please give us your needed try with jsfiddle or give working example so we can get what your need is or where you are wrong.?

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara, Can not you understand my question?

Comment: This is a fiddle with current code - https://jsfiddle.net/kupLs5zn/2/

Comment: when click on icon button, then I need to display "contents" div with an animation to left side

Comment: try :https://jsfiddle.net/kupLs5zn/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I did it by modifying your CSS code:

```
.contents {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #ebebeb;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.icon:hover + .contents { visibility: visible; }
```

Have a look at [this **JSFiddle demo** here](https://jsfiddle.net/kupLs5zn/)

Comment: Ahs N, this is not what I need

Comment: Is the solution I suggested close to what you require? If so, what is to be changed?Add animation maybe?

Comment: Actually I need to display "contents" `DIV` when click on `icon` image.

Comment: Ahs N. No.. check this link - http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition1

Comment: I am looking for solution something like that.